# Reading data from file and putting it into struct type

Tags: c, file, struct

Im new to C programming and trying to make a function that will read file (score.txt) that includes 10 players and their scores -

```
manager 1000
manager 900
manager 800
manager 700 
manager 600
manager 500
manager 400
manager 300
manager 200
manager 100
```

I want to put this data into struct type

```
    struct player{
    // name of the player (avoid usage of spaces in name)
    char name[30];
    // player's score
    int score;
};
```

My code right now looks like this

```
int load(struct player list[]){
    FILE* fp = fopen("score.txt", "r");
    
    size_t size;
    fread(&size, sizeof size, 1, fp);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        fread(&list[i], sizeof list[i], 1, fp);
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

but I get segmentation fault if I run it. What needs to be changed? Thanks!

Comment: Quite a number of things wrong here, and my crystal ball tells me there might be other problems in the code you didn't show.  It seems you're attempting to read the file as if it contains binary data, except it's not opened in binary mode and actually it's a text file.  So all of that's wrong.  You never test if the file was opened, and we can't see how you allocated memory for this "list".  Most likely the issue is that you read `size` as a binary value.  Where is this in your text file?  It's probably a text value.  Use your debugger, look at the value of `size`.  I bet it's huge.

Answer (score 0):

use `getline` to read the lines and split the line the first part will be name and the second part will be the score.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct player{
    // name of the player (avoid usage of spaces in name)
    char name[30];
    // player's score
    int score;
};

int load(struct player list[], int length){
    FILE* fp = fopen("score.txt", "r");

    //size_t size;
    //fread(&size,, 1, fp);

    //for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
    //    fread(&list[i], sizeof list[i], 1, fp);
    //}
    struct player input;
    int count = 0;
    /*while(fread(&input, sizeof(struct player), 1, fp)){
        printf ("name = %s score %d\n", input.name,
        input.score);
        //list[count].name = input.name;
        strcpy(list[count].name, input.name);
        list[count].score = input.score;
        count++;
        if(count >= length)
                break;
    }*/
    char * line=NULL;
    ssize_t read ;
    size_t len =0;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
        strcpy(list[count].name, strtok(line, " "));
        list[count].score = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        count++;
        if(count >= length)
                break;

    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

int main(){
        struct player array[10];
        load(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(struct player));
        for(int i = 0 ;i<10;i++)
                printf("name : %s score %d\n",array[i].name, array[i].score);
        return 0;
}
```

## Output:

```
$ gcc fileop.c && ./a.exe
fileop.c: In function 'load':
fileop.c:39:22: warning: implicit declaration of function 'atoi' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   39 |  list[count].score = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
      |                      ^~~~
Retrieved line of length 13:
manager 1000
Retrieved line of length 12:
manager 900
Retrieved line of length 12:
manager 800
Retrieved line of length 13:
manager 700
Retrieved line of length 12:
manager 600
Retrieved line of length 12:
manager 500
Retrieved line of length 12:
manager 400
Retrieved line of length 12:
manager 300
Retrieved line of length 12:
manager 200
Retrieved line of length 12:
manager 100
name : manager score 1000
name : manager score 900
name : manager score 800
name : manager score 700
name : manager score 600
name : manager score 500
name : manager score 400
name : manager score 300
name : manager score 200
name : manager score 100
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a thorough answer! I somewhat managed to make working program using fprintf/fscanf but your code is obviously much cleaner and safer. I will need to read up more on atoi/strtok though as I have never used them before.